# Javascript countdown Glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change this default seconds timer to a Seconds countdown timer but its not working some how

here is the script which i am trying to edit

https://codepen.io/martingrand/pen/pqxtc

Here is the script which i made

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmXbZR

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

my jquery

```
var sec = 155;
calcValues();
var intvel = setInterval(calcValues, 1000);

function calcValues() {
    $('.counter .to')
        .addClass('hide')
        .removeClass('to')
        .addClass('from')
        .removeClass('hide')
        .addClass('n')
        .find('span:not(.shadow)').each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).text(getSec(true));
    });
    $('.counter .from:not(.n)')
        .addClass('hide')
        .addClass('to')
        .removeClass('from')
        .removeClass('hide')
    .find('span:not(.shadow)').each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).text(getSec(false));
    });
    $('.counter .n').removeClass('n');
}

function getSec(next) {
    var d = new Date();
    if (next) {
        sec--;
        if (sec == 0) {
            clearInterval(intvel);
        }
    } else if(sec == 60) {
        sec = 0;
    }

    return (sec == 10 ? '0' + sec : sec);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to modify?

Comment: What is that you want to do here? The 1st code pen does do a countdown timer in seconds already - what do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is wrong

```
return (sec == 10 ? '0' + sec : sec);
```

You are saying if seconds is equal to 10, than add a zero. It should be if less than 10.

```
return (sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec);
```

Now for the issue, seems like calling your getSeconds twice is your problem. So instead of calling it twice, do it once.

```
function calcValues() {

    var secs = getSec(true);  //store it
    $('.counter .to')
        .addClass('hide')
        .removeClass('to')
        .addClass('from')
        .removeClass('hide')
        .addClass('n')
        .find('span:not(.shadow)').each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).text(secs);  //use it
    });
    $('.counter .from:not(.n)')
        .addClass('hide')
        .addClass('to')
        .removeClass('from')
        .removeClass('hide')
    .find('span:not(.shadow)').each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).text(secs);  //use it
    });
    $('.counter .n').removeClass('n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define the sec variable globally. When calling *sec(true)*, the global sec variable will be decreased by one. Then, when you call *sec(false)* it will give the same result as you previous call.

This should work better:

```
var sec_counter = 10;
calcValues();
var intvel = setInterval(calcValues, 1000);
function calcValues() {
    $('.counter .to')
        .addClass('hide')
        .removeClass('to')
        .addClass('from')
        .removeClass('hide')
        .addClass('n')
        .find('span:not(.shadow)').each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).text(getSec(true));
    });
    $('.counter .from:not(.n)')
        .addClass('hide')
        .addClass('to')
        .removeClass('from')
        .removeClass('hide')
    .find('span:not(.shadow)').each(function (i, el) {
        $(el).text(getSec(false));
    });
    $('.counter .n').removeClass('n');
    sec_counter --;
}  
function getSec(next) {
    var sec = sec_counter;
    if (next) {

        if (sec == 0) {
            clearInterval(intvel);
        }
        else{
          sec --; 
        }
    } else if(sec == 60) {
        sec = 0;
    }
    return (sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec);
}
```